# Regex: Find substring starts with AND end with from a string and replace a word from substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

Possible inputs:

Input1:

```
Hi John, I have recently..
```

Input2:

```
 hi , I have...
```

Input3:

```
 Hi Hans, I have...
```

Input4:

```
Hi, I have...
```

I want a regex to add or replace the name. Starts with `Hi` (ignore case) AND ends with `,`. (Replace only first occurrence)

E.g If I want to replace it with `David`

Output: `Hi David, I have recently..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\S+)\s*\S*(?=,)
```

You can use this.Replace by by `$1 David`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/7

```
var re = /^(\S+)\s*\S*(?=,)/gmi; 
var str = 'Hi John, I have recently..\nhi , I have...\nHi Hans, I have...\nHi, I have...';
var subst = '$1 David'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RegEx`.  Just add `space` right after `$1`.

```
var regX = /^(hi)(\s?([a-z]+)?)?(?=,.+)/igm; 
var str = 'Hi John, I have recently..\nhi , I have...\nHi Hans, I have...\nHi, I have...';
var sub = '$1 David';
var result = str.replace(regX, sub);
```